# I am updating a variable through text field and trying to print it in the console but it is printing previous value instead of updated value

Tags: install4j

I am updating a variable in the text field and trying to print it in the console but it is printing the previous value instead of updated value

String symbolicName =(String)context.getVariable("symbolic.domain.name");
console.println(symbolicName);// it is printing old value insted of updated value

I am expecting updated value it is printing old value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is updated when the user clicks on the "Next" button. To update all bound variables on the form before that, execute

```
formEnvironment.saveFormComponents();
```